# Change menu color when you scroll

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I encounter the following problem, if anyone can help me. Can I change the color of the menu in the image when I scroll from black to white?

[image]

---

[image]

I would be very grateful.

Comment: please provide your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this :
[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/ZyKar/3/)

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 800) {
    $('.className').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.className').fadeOut();
  }
});
```